# Filter null values of the entity framework query

Tags: entity-framework

```
 var invoice = (from i in Catalog.Invoices
                  where (i.Id == invoiceId)
                  select i)
                  .Include(i => i.Appointment.Service)
                  .Include(i => i.Appointment.Allocations.Select(a => a.Service))
                  .Include(i => i.Appointment.Allocations.Select(e => e.Employee))
                  .FirstOrDefault();

var inv = invoice.Appointment.Allocations.Select(e => e.Employee);
```

[image]

**My Question :** How to filter the null values from above query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a `Where` clause to the query to filter out the `null` values.

Either after the `Select`:

```
var inv = invoice.Appointment.Allocations.Select(e => e.Employee).Where(e => e != null);
```

or before the `Select`:

```
var inv = invoice.Appointment.Allocations.Where(e => e.Employee != null).Select(e => e.Employee);
```